# A workflow which have 20 sessions were working fine for sometimes. But suddenly it was running only 10 sessions and need to manually start it

Tags: session

A workflow which have 20 sessions were working fine for sometimes. But suddenly it was running only 10 sessions and stop so we need to go and start task manually from there. What would be the reason for it.

I just manually run the other tasks